# How to rename a custom ID field in django to the default

Tags: python, django, primary-key, django-south

A long while back, I designed a few Django models with fields like:

```
documentUUID = models.AutoField("a unique ID for each document",
                                    primary_key=True)
```

I thought this was good -- I was being explicit about things -- but I've since realized that I'd love to purge my code of these references, and move towards a more standard implementation.

My goals are thus:

1. Rename the field in the DB so that it's as if I never had the custom `primary_key` field.
2. Remove these field definitions from my models so the default takes over.
3. Refactor these values out of my code.

Comment: why do you want to do that? is it causing any issues ?

Comment: One approach would be to do a `manage.py dumpdata --natural-keys`, change the json, then change the schema, and then do the loaddata

Comment: You'll have to do it by hands, of course. Install [south](http://south.aeracode.org/) and… good luck!

Comment: Dumping data is definitely not a possibility -- we have way too much. We're renaming some other fields right now, so cleaning this up is just part of good hygiene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I asked this I was forced **by the code** to do some experimentation.

Looks like what you can do is simply:

1. Remove the field from the model
2. Generate the schema migration.
3. Edit the migration to rename the field to id (`db.rename_column('Document', 'documentUUID', 'id')`)
4. Migrate it and update all your code with a mondo find and replace.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [south](http://south.aeracode.org/)? It is a tool created for precisely this problem.

Comment: specifically a south data migration is what you require:
http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html#data-migrations

Comment: Actually, see my answer, where I explain the schema migration I used.